# How do you make the user change a value in the domain class in Grails

Tags: grails

Is there a way to change a value in the domain class by having the user input the new value ? 
so if we have a view page, and an input box, whatever is entered in the input box will modify a specific value in the domain class

for e.g:

```
class User {
    String userName
}
```

in views page:

```
<input type="userName" action="changeUsername">
```

Comment: Take a look at [Grails scaffolding](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/guide/scaffolding.html), it is a great resource to understand how Grails works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take Alidad's advice:

> Take a look at [Grails scaffolding](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/guide/scaffolding.html), it is a great resource to
>   understand how Grails works.–  Alidad

That being said we can look at what is generated when running `grails generate-all testapp.User` and how it relates to your question.

generate-all with create a Controller and Views based off of your domain class User.

```
package testapp

class User {

    String userName

    static constraints = {
        userName()
    }
}
```

Notice the static constraints *(this is a great place to add validation)* but all you need in order to generate Views and controllers related to specific values is to add it to your static constraints within your domain class.

You want to be able to update a domain class. 
Well the code to do this has been generated for us! 
if you look at views/user/edit.gsp

```
<g:form url="[resource:userInstance, action:'update']" method="PUT" >
                <g:hiddenField name="version" value="${userInstance?.version}" />
                <fieldset class="form">
                    <g:render template="form"/>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset class="buttons">
                    <g:actionSubmit class="save" action="update" value="${message(code: 'default.button.update.label', default: 'Update')}" />
                </fieldset>
            </g:form>
```

This will create a form to update the current user we have selected `userInstance` in this case.

Also an important observation is `<g:form url="[resource:userInstance, action:'update']" method="PUT" >` this tells us which controller will be called based on the resource and method will be called based on the action *(You can look more into good design for controller calling here [Grails WebServices REST](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/guide/webServices.html#REST))*

This will call controllers/testapp/UserController.groovy - update which takes a User instance

```
@Transactional
def update(User userInstance) {
        if (userInstance == null) {
            notFound()
            return
        }

        if (userInstance.hasErrors()) {
            respond userInstance.errors, view:'edit'
            return
        }

        userInstance.save flush:true

        request.withFormat {
            form multipartForm {
                flash.message = message(code: 'default.updated.message', args: [message(code: 'User.label', default: 'User'), userInstance.id])
                redirect userInstance
            }
            '*'{ respond userInstance, [status: OK] }
        }
    }
```

Which you can see does some checks to make sure the instance exists and doesn't have errors (which is based off of the validation you add in your Domain Class) then saves your updated User Instance  and then returns a message back. It is also a good practice to move the "work" out of your controller and into a service class.

But there are a lot of different ways to skin a cat.  This communication between view and Controller to update a Domain class can be done in many different ways.

Well I hope that makes sense, just play around and have fun!